# Should About page be named Abouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails naming convention says controllers should be plural, as should associated views.  Models are singular.

That makes sense if you have a controller name orders.  It is most likely going to have a model named order.  However, should the about page be named abouts?  That seems odd.

The about page isn't going to have any associated model. Does that make a difference with singular vs plural naming conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static content pages (eg. 'about us', 'terms and conditions', 'privacy policy', etc.) I typically stray away from typical REST conventions.

I would create a single `PagesController` and have one action for each page (eg. `def about_us; end`. Each action would just render the view with the content for that page.

Answer (score 1):

By following the Rails convention of naming, you can standardize a lot of things in your project but there can be exceptions.

You can use `about` instead of `abouts` if you want, then name the file as `about_controller.rb` and inside the file, have the class name as: `class AboutController`. You have to match the class and the file name, then it will work just fine. Rails won't complaint about this.

But again, it depends on the use case. In this use case, I don't think you really need a controller for `about` page :-) You should be able to handle that in any other multi-purpose/common controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails `pluralize` method to generate plurals. Use rails console for this.

```
"about".pluralize
```